# Sort items according to features

Tags: prestashop

I have a shop on PrestaShop 1.5 and I need to display products based on "features" criteria. To do this, I figured I need to modify (or clone and modify) `homefeatured` module. But how? I can't seem to find out what to add.

The file `homefeatured.php` only has `$category` and `$products` (with usage of `$category`). I'm totally in the dark, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Do you like to show product on certain creiterial. Or you like to show special product. As homefeatured product serve the featured product. So if you add any product as featured it will show on home featured.

Comment: I need to display products only with certain `attribute` value.